Given a single eigenvector, find original matrix
Assume a column vector $u$ of size $2^N$.
I want to impose that this vector is the eigenvector $u_{\lambda}$ with $\lambda=0$ eigenvalue of a $2^N\times 2^N$ matrix $A$, i.e. $A u_{0} = 0$.
Assuming this is the only condition, how would I determine the matrix $A$? I know that $A$ will not be unique, but I would like to know how much I can extract from a single vector $u$.
For example, for $N=2$: Assume $u=(1,-1,1,1)^T/2$. It turns out that in this case, the matrix is
\begin{equation}A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
This can be done by hand. However, as we increase the size $N$, this becomes tedious and non-obvious.
Update: For example, assume the non-trivial case of $N=3$,
$u=(1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1)^T/2\sqrt{2}$

Find all solutions $v$ of $ v u_0=0$, choose $n$ of them to form the rows of $A$.

@JensSchwaiger and what is $v$? Is it just a general vector with N parameters?

@JensSchwaiger is your approach to find all the orthogonal vectors to $u_0$ and then just construct the diagonal matrix?

Is it the case that the entries of $u$ are $\pm 1/\sqrt{2^N}$ and you are looking for a matrix whose entries are all $-1$ or $0$ or $1$?

yes, you are right. My vector $u$ is always going to look like that. And about $A$, that is correct. Still, because we know little information (only 1 eigenvector ), $A$ can be quite difficult to find

You can get $1/n$th of the matrix back, more or less. For simplicity suppose $u_0 = e_1$ is the first standard basis vector. The condition $A e_1 = 0$ is precisely saying that the first column of $A$ is zero. Every other entry can be chosen arbitrarily.
The general case can be solved by a change of basis starting with this case. (There are many essentially equivalent approaches.)
Here's an explicit general recipe. Given a non-zero length $n$ column vector $u$ and a scalar $\lambda$, you can generate every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ where $Au = \lambda u$ as follows.
First pick a basis containing $u$, say $$u, v_2, v_3, \ldots, v_n.$$ This can be done in many ways, but the following will always work. If $u$ is not a multiple of any of the standard basis vectors $e_i$, use $u, e_2, e_3, \ldots, e_n$. If instead $u$ is a multiple of some particular $e_i$, use $u, e_2, e_3, \ldots, e_{i-1}, e_1, e_{i+1}, \ldots, e_n$, where the $i$th position has been replaced with $e_1$.
Having picked such a basis of column vectors, let $$P = \begin{bmatrix}u & v_2 & v_3 & \cdots & v_n\end{bmatrix}.$$ Let $B$ be any $n \times n$ matrix whose first column is all $0$'s except the upper left entry is $\lambda$, with the rest of the entries completely arbitrary. Finally let $$A = PBP^{-1}.$$
This has your desired property. Why? By construction $Pe_1 = u$ and $Be_1 = \lambda e_1$, so $$Au = PBP^{-1}u = PBe_1 = P\lambda e_1 = \lambda Pe_1 = \lambda u.$$
The above procedure has the property that, for each fixed $P$, iterating over all such $B$ will produce all such $A$ each exactly once.

I don't think I fully understand your approach. Could you give me more specific example with the update I did?

I've added an explicit recipe. That's probably as much detail as I can give.

Thanks for the detailed answer! If I understand correctly the main steps are to find all the other orthonormal vectors to $u$ and then construct $P$. About $B$, is the matrix going to be diagonal by construction or only the 1st entry with $\lambda=0$?

The basis doesn't need to consist of orthonormal vectors, and my suggestion will not produce an orthonormal basis. I described $B$ in the post precisely, and it's definitely not diagonal in general, though you could choose it to be. I'm getting the sense that your understanding of this material is too shaky to build on properly.
